# How to read model and collection value by underscore.js

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

My view is bind both model and collection

```
 var editUserPanel = new List.EditUserPanel({
                    collection: roll_st,
                    model: dm
                });
```

I have used in html

```
  <%  _.each(items, function(item){ if(item.category == "STGroup") { %>
    <option selected> <%= item.name %> </option>
   <% } }) %>
```

When my view is only bind to collection ,I am able read the collection value .But when both are bind , I get error .

Answer (score 1):

write a serialise function in view, which will read model or collection and return expected map of key value pairs for template. And while rendering template use output from serialize as dataObject.

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    serialize: function(){
        return {
            items:this.collection.toJSON(), //array from collection
            modelValues:this.model.toJSON() // map from model
        }
    },
    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(_.template(your_template_html, this.serialize()))
    }
})
```